# Array to string conversion when upgrading from php 5 to php 7

Tags: php, php-7

I have upgraded to php 7 and now this code throws a array to string conversion error.

```
$categories[$prd['category_id']]['products'][$prd['product_id']] = $prd;
```

The `$categories` contains this:

```
array(2) {
  [278515]=>
  array(8) {
    ["category_id"]=>
    string(6) "278515"
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["category_name"]=>
    string(8) "Desserts"
    ["category_description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["category_image"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["wholesaler_id"]=>
    string(3) "296"
    ["category_position"]=>
    string(2) "21"
    ["products"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["category_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["category_name"]=>
    string(11) "No Category"
    ["category_description"]=>
    string(20) "category_description"
    ["category_image"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["wholesaler_id"]=>
    string(3) "296"
    ["category_position"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["products"]=>
    string(4) "1182"
  }
}
```

And `$prd` contains this:

```
array(11) {
  ["product_id"]=>
  string(7) "4195072"
  ["category_id"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["parent_id"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["product_num"]=>
  string(1) "7"
  ["product_name"]=>
  string(18) "Chicken Pizza, 12""
  ["product_description"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["product_image"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["product_price"]=>
  string(4) "0.00"
  ["wholesaler_id"]=>
  string(3) "296"
  ["is_variant"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["is_mealdeal"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

This bit of code used to work in php 5 But has stopped ever since i upgraded to php 7. I have gone through similar posts in the forum but so far nothing worked for me.

Comment: Did you debug? What is in the different variables stored? What type is `$prd` and are the different keys `product_id` and `category_id` set? At the frist glance, there is no `$category[278515]['products]` array. So just debug every var you are using and then you 'll find the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$prd['category_id']` is `0`, and `$prd['product_id']` is `4195072`, so

```
$categories[$prd['category_id']]['products'][$prd['product_id']] = $prd;
```

translates to

```
$categories[0]['products']['4195072'] = $prd;
```

and since `$categories[0]['products']` is a string (`'1182'`), PHP treats this as attempting to assign a value to the portion of the string starting from location 4195072. Since `$prd` is an array, that gives you an array to string conversion error.

Comment: Ahh yes I added the ['products'] to use for the amount of products the category has and forgot about it. Stupid mistake, but thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`$categories[$prd['category_id']]['products'][$prd['product_id']] = $prd;`

In your case `$categories[$prd['category_id']]['products']` is a string, but you're using it as array.

Either `'products'` key should be an array in your original data:

```
array(2) {
  [278515]=>
  array(8) {
    ["category_id"]=>
    string(6) "278515"
    ...
    ["products"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
```

**OR**

You should use different array key for holding product info list. Something like `$categories[$prd['category_id']]['products_list'][$prd['product_id']] = $prd;`

It would be good to initialize this key when you're creating initial data